# How to use the input from 1 python script in another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 python script files, say, `R.py`, `N.py`, `P.py`. I use `P` to run `N` which gets data from `R`, by calling `R's` function. I want to use the input from `P` in an `if` statment in `R.py`. I know I can change `R.py` to receive an `arg`, but I have to change `R.py` a lot, because the `if` is not in the function I am calling. Is there a way for me to capture the `input` from `P.py` and use it in `R's` `if`?

`P.py`:

```
import N.py as n

lang = input("Enter the language set?: )
n.agent(name=name, learning=lr, is_remote=is_remote, is_bi=is_bi, batch=batch, 
        no_char_codes=no_char_codes, classes=classes, data_set=lang)
```

`N.py`:

```
import R as r

r.retrieve(start, batch_counter, is_remote)
```

`R.py`(incomplete):

```
# Here I want: 
# if lang == 'E' use the below, 
# else use something else.
# but the lang is coming from P.py:
char_codes = {0: 0, "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6, "g": 7, 
              "h": 8, "i": 9, "j": 10, "k": 11, "l": 12}

pos_values = {0: 0, "CC": 1, "CD": 2, "DT": 3, "EX": 4, "FW": 5, "IN": 6, 
              "JJ": 7, "JJR": 8, "JJS": 9, "LS": 10}

def retrieve(start, end, is_remote):
```

Comment: care to share a minimal example of your existing code? this will help us respond with a solution that fits your needs. also have a look at [mcve].

Comment: @jp_data_analysis: I have added some code.

Comment: People use there personal time to answer questions, if one of the answers below answer your question, please mark it as such, and maybe give an up vote if appropriate.

Comment: @SteveJ: Not the answers I am looking for. In the ended I changed R.py to make it work.

Comment: Then answer your own question for others to use, ask for follow up, or delete the question if you don't think it is useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

I could see the answer to this by incorporating the reading and writing functions of python. Make a text document that all 3 .py files can view, and so for example, if p.py provides an input of "hello" (If you want to use a string literal as input). You could have the p.py program open the shared text document with:

```
#(from p.py file)
input = "hello"
f = open("C:/Users/Directory/shared_file.txt", "w")
f.write(input)
f.close()

#(Then from r.py file)
f = open("C:/Users/Directory/shared_file.txt", "r")
input = f.readline() #or f.read() if its only 1 line with no '\n' or '\t' spacing
f.close()
input = str(input) #just to insure the input read is string for this example
if input == "Hi":
    print("True")
elif input == "Hello":
    print("second True")
else:
    print("False")
```

This script should print "False". This is how I have my programs communicate with each other. Other than that I think you can have a parameter that should be expected from one .py to be returned by another .py but I don't know how to do that! I hope this helped maybe give you a different perspective on how to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have 3 files:

**`mod1.py`**:

```
condition = input()
```

**`mod2.py`**:

```
import mod1 as m1
```

**`mod3.py`**:

```
import mod2 as m2
```

If I want to use an object from `mod1.py` inside `mod3.py` I can simply chain  my modules in `mod3.py` to:

```
import mod2 as m2
if m2.m1.condition:
    print(m2.m1.condition)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it in reverse -- input() would be in mod3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying its pretty or that I recommend it, and it is almost certainly a bad idea -- but, if you absolutely have to.....

**P.py**

```
import shelve

user_input = "Some user input"
with shelve.open('my_store') as holder:
    holder['input'] = user_input

import N
```

**R.py**

```
import shelve

user_input = None

with shelve.open('my_store') as holder:
    user_input = holder['input']

print(user_input)
```